# How do you generate a Intuit Partner Platform RequestId?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add invoices to QuickBooks by doing a POST without using the SDK.

```
<Add . . . RequestId="guid">
   <Object xsi:type="Invoice">
```

I am getting an error saying my requestID is invalid, which I generated using "Guid.NewGuid()", I assume because of the dashes;

cvc-pattern-valid: Value '210bf66b-9b4b-433e-adf0-dc655eb1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-z|A-Z|0-9]*' for type 'guid'.

Does anyone know how to generate a valid RequestId guid that can be used in a POST to Intuit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please exclude the dashes - Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");